# Delete row fails with "the specified index doesn't exsists"

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I want to make a really simple DELETE-statement:

```
DELETE FROM appliances WHERE (id = 7)
```

But I allways get this error:

```
DELETE FROM appliances WHERE (id = 7)
Fehlerquelle: SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
Fehlermeldung: Der angegebene Index ist nicht vorhanden. [ PK_analog_config ]
```

Translated in english the error text says:

```
The given index doesn't exsists. [ PK_analog_config ]
```

the table appliances:

```
id int not null primary key,
name NVarChar(20) not null,
status NVarChar(100) null,
location NVarChar(100) not null,
port int not null,
```

(no foreign keys or indexes)

the table analog_config:
primary key is a combination of id(from appliances) and name.
So id is also a foreign key that points to appliances.id (On delete CASCADE).

```
appliance_id int not null primary key,
value_name NVarChar(20) not null primary key,
access_rights NVachar(2) not null,
min_value numeric(18,2) not null,
max_value numeric(18,2) not null,
unit nvarchar(20) not null,

fk_analog_values_appliances: 
PK-table= appliances (id)
FK-table= analog_config (appliance_id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I don't understand the error message. Which index do they mean? In the analog_config table there is no data.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you provide the table structure for both tables and also do you have record on id 7?

Comment: Could it be that the database has been set up with a 1:1 or 1:many relationship between those tables (ie, there MUST be an entry in the analog_config table, but that you bypassed the integrity checks to insert only in the appliances table?  I'm not sure what would happen in those circumstances, but it might result in the error you are seeing...

Comment: There is no foreign key set on the appliance table. Even if I would add an entry in analo_config with the appliance_id = 7, there will occur the same error.
An entry in appliances with id=7 exists.